# Prime factor $>250000$ for $1002004008016032$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I need to find a prime factor, $p$, of $1002004008016032$ such that $p \gt 250000$. Now this is a very large number and I know it would be stupid of me to factorize such a large number into its prime factors . Any help how I can solve this ?

Comment: $2^5\times 3^2\times 7\times 109^2\times 167\times 250501$

Comment: How did you figure out such nasty factors :)

Comment: Go here $\longrightarrow$ https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM It is a calculator and strictly works for integers. When a decimal is put, it will round the result to the nearest integer. When given an equation or inequality, it will return $-1$ if true and $0$ if false. It also has many other functions you can learn :)

Answer (score 19):

$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$

Taking $x=10^3,y=2$, we get

$1002004008016032=x^5+x^4y+x^3y^2+x^2y^3+xy^4+y^5=\frac{x^6-y^6}{x-y}$

Also,

$\frac{x^6-y^6}{x-y} = (x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2)(x^2-xy+y^2)$

=$1002\times1002004\times998004 = 1002\times16\times250501\times249501$

Hence, the prime number , $p\gt250000$ is $250501$

Comment: If there exist "nerd-answers" at all: then this is one... :-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms   And now I am having so much fun asking Wolfram to factor expressions of the form $\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$

Comment: @CopyPasteIt - see my joy on analyzing this in this essay on my webspace http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf Perhaps you like that approach as well... :)

Answer (score 0):

The OP was looking for any help. If all you have as an aid is access to the Python programming language, you can code this:

```
L = 1002004008016032
b = 250001

while True:
    r = L % b
    if r == 0:
        print(b)
        break
    b = b + 1

for n in range(2,int(b**.5)+1):
    if b % n == 0:
        print(b, 'is not a prime')
        raise SystemExit

print(b, 'is a prime')
raise SystemExit
```

giving the output

```
250501
250501 is a prime
```

ANS: $250501$

If it turned out that $250501$ was not a prime, you would have to edit the while loop, changing it to

```
while True:
    r = L % b
    if r == 0 and b != 250501:
        print(b)
        break
    b = b + 1
```

and then rerun the program to get the next factor candidate.

It is possible that many reruns would be required to find the answer using this technique, but the code can also be easily modified with a *one-run* requirement.

Comment: For a simpler programmatic solution, just type factor 1002004008016032  in a Linux/Unix terminal

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, and there is also Wolfram. But I was interested in the underlying programming logic, so I put in my 'only access to...' restraint.